# How Autolayout constraint First Item and Second Item works?

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode6

If I have UIView with top 100 left 120 right 120 how exactly First Item and Second Item relationship work. After going through Apple document each relationship has a linear equation with an expression as.

```
firstItem.firstItemAttribute == secondItem.secondItemAttribute * multiplier + constant
```

With this equation for **top leading** constraint with relation

- First Item **Safe Area.Leading**
- Relation **=**
- Second Item = **MyView.Leading**
- Constant **120**

with equation the First Item And Second Item I understood. But Problem for me in understanding when I do the **reverse** the second item constant changes to **- 120** and layout has no effect after the change. Why negative has no effect and what is its use for?
**Xcode** provides a set of properties for FirstItem & SecondItem like leading, center, trailing when we need to switch this properties.

Comment: your url not working. please show us required UI .

Comment: @dahiya_boy Its just as simple UI with top, leading and trailing constraint.I want to understand how first item and second item works

Comment: Can you please explain what is unclear to you. Whether you wanted to give constraints from storyboard or programatically. BTW preferred choice is from storyboard.

Comment: From storyboard

Answer (score 2):

- First Item = **Safe Area.Leading** --- that's the "left edge" of the Safe Area
- Second Item = **MyView.Leading** --- that's the "left edge" of your view

So, **"left edge" of the Safe Area** to **"left edge" of your view** equals `120`, or, your view is `120` pts ***from*** the Safe Area (to the right).

- First Item = **MyView.Leading** --- that's the "left edge" of your view
- Second Item = **Safe Area.Leading** --- that's the "left edge" of the Safe Area

So, **"left edge" of your view** to **"left edge" of the Safe Area** equals `-120`, or, the left edge of Safe Area is `-120` pts ***from*** your view (to the left).

If you change `-120` to `120`, that would put the left edge of the Safe Area `+120` pts, or 120 pts to the right, of your view's left edge, which would push the view off the screen to the left.

**Edit:**

For a little more clarity...

With "SafeArea.Leading -> myView.Leading", you are saying *"put myView's left edge 120-pts from the left edge of the Safe Area"*

When you swap them to "myView.Leading -> SafeArea.Leading", you are saying *"put SafeArea's left edge **minus** 120-pts from the left edge of myView"*.

---

In general, when using Interface Builder, you leave the order alone... because you are visually laying out your elements, and IB knows how to define the constraints.

More often where you will ***see*** a difference, is when setting up constraints in code.

For example, to put a subview (red) inside a containing view (blue), with 20-pts padding on all four sides like this:

[image]

your code might look like this:

```
    let myContainerView = UIView()
    myContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myContainerView.backgroundColor = .blue

    // add container view to self view
    view.addSubview(myContainerView)

    // constrain container view center X and Y, width and height both 240-pts
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        myContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        myContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        myContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
        myContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),

        ])

    let myInnerView = UIView()
    myInnerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myInnerView.backgroundColor = .red

    // add inner view to container view
    myContainerView.addSubview(myInnerView)

    // constrain inner view with 20-pts padding on all four sides
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        // top and left are 20-pts from superview top and left
        myInnerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:
            myContainerView.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
        myInnerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:
            myContainerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),

        // bottom and right are *minus* 20-pts from superview bottom and right
        myInnerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:
            myContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        myInnerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:
            myContainerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

        ])
```

You will note that the ***trailing*** and ***bottom*** constraints of the inner view must be negative, because you want them to be 20-pts *away from* the trailing and bottom edges of the container view.

Comment: How it will be -120 and it has no effect on UI

Comment: Nice clarification I got why it is negative. But I have one more question why Xocde gives these Attributes with the first item and second item with reverse and other options ??? Any use without programmatically in interface builder ???